# How to pass in api key?

Tags: c#, google-maps

I have searched everywhere and I cannot find out how to pass my API key in with my request.  I am setup to run from a specific IP address.  I keep hitting my limit though.  I think I am also hitting my time limits.  I will introduce a sleep in my code.  Otherwise, is there anything else I can check?? I am using the distance matrix with json output.  I have turned on Google Maps API V3.  I have a key and have a project.  It seems like the service is still treating me like a free customer.

```
string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" +
            origin + "&destinations=" + sDestination + "&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false&units=imperial";
```

I have also tried two more approaches with my key and I get a denied request from both of them.

```
string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" +
            origin + "&destinations=" + sDestination + "&key=mykey&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false&units=imperial";
```

and

```
string url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" +
            origin + "&destinations=" + sDestination + "&key={mykey}&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false&units=imperial";
```

I was not sure if the curly braces were required or not.  Both of the later lines of code result in request denials.

Comment: Apparently the free "keys" are no longer supported methods of working this and are not required.  Also, after a lot of testing, I found out that if I pass in an address with a "#" character, it fails as well.  I was hitting this and did not realize it.  I don't know what else to add here to get my ban on posting lifted!  I have resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you just pass the key right in the URL, at least for the regular maps API.  Take a look at the ["Hello World" example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HelloWorld) in the documentation.  It might work the same for the distance matrix.  Have you tried it that way?

Comment: Thanks.  That is basically what I was having hard time finding.  Interesting now that I am getting a "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED".  Some suggest that the sensor type is required.  That is in there.  No luck.  I will keep digging.

Comment: So, I am really stuck here.  I am apparently banned from asking more questions, but this question is still not answered.  I have provided as much information as possible.

Comment: If you are a paying customer, I assume there is a support line you can call for assistance?

Comment: They say all their support is through stackoverflow now.